# MongoDB - How to group and count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

1. For each subject type, list the name of the subject type and the total number of subjects that belong to the subject type.

Below is the database:
[Pastebin subject.js](https://pastebin.com/g7ySAeFD)

What I've tried

For the first statement:

```
db.Subject.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"subject.$type","count":{"$sum":1}}}])
result: { "_id" : "subject.$type", "count" : 7 }
```

```
db.Subject.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$subject"},{"$group":{"_id":"$type"}}])
result: { "_id" : null }
```

```
db.Subject.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$subject"},{"$group":{"_id":{"subject.type":"$subject.type"}},"count":{"$sum":1}}])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by _id with `"$subject.type"`.

```
db.Subject.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$subject.type",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RbBA9Y2wGOt)